pyautogui.pixel(x,y) rgb values always changing even when pixel color isn't changing
This doesn't even happen all the time, sometimes it works perfectly fine and consistently returns the same rgb values, but a majority of other times it returns rgb values that are close to the actual color but still not the same.
To test the pyautogui.pixel I wrote the below code:
while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    print(pyautogui.pixel(146,488))
    time.sleep(1)

For some reason it works well for black screens (returning 0,0,0 always) but when I'm checking the rgb for a pixel for, lets say, light blue, it would give me something close like purple, but never the specific rgb values of the color. This value would also continuously change.

What OS is this? Have you inadvertantly chosen a pixel corresponding to a clock or something changing? Have you tried swapping the x & y coordinates in case you have them the wrong way around? Or doubling them in case you have a retina display?

I made sure I knew what the pixel location was with displayMousePosition, so the pixel color is definitely not changing. I wouldn't think doubling or OS would be the issue, considering that no matter what location it is, it still gives changing values.

You still didn't state your OS.

Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 23H2
Installed on ‎10/‎8/‎2023
OS build 22631.3737
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1009.0

If you just have installed pyautogui, try to restart the computer. Then the problem may be resolved.
